# Spring Boot with Jersey and Spring Security OAuth2

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-security, jersey-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

Following the sample from Spring Boot: [example code from GitHub](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/tree/master/spring-boot-samples/spring-boot-sample-jersey) everything seems to work fine.

But when I integrate Spring Boot Security OAuth2 in the project, my OAuth2 endpoints stop working. There's a warning in the logs:

`2017-05-04 08:56:24.109  WARN 2827 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent  : A servlet request to the URI http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth/token contains form parameters in the request body but the request body has been consumed by the servlet or a servlet filter accessing the request parameters. Only resource methods using @FormParam will work as expected. Resource methods consuming the request body by other means will not work as expected.`

Which makes me think even though I'm not registering the endpoint, Jersey is capturing it and processing the body, making Spring MVC unable to accept the request...

My Jersey Config is:

```
@Component
public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {

    public JerseyConfig() {
        register(InfoController.class);
    }

}
```

And my info controller is very simple:

```
@Component
@Path("/me")
@Produces("application/json")
public class InfoController {
  @GET
  public String meAction() {
    return "Hi";
  }
}
```

And finally, the call I'm trying to make and it's causing the warning in the logs:

`curl -X POST -u CLIENT_APPLICATION:123456789 http://127.0.0.1:8080/oauth/token -H "Accept: application/json" -d "password=aaa&username=aa&grant_type=password&client_id=CLIENT_APPLICATION"`

Is there a known incompatibility between the two projects (`spring-boot-starter-jersey` and `spring-security-oauth2` in that sense?

Removing the Jersey configuration makes it all work, but I need to use it on my controllers.

My configuration for OAuth2 is:

```
@Configuration
public class OAuth2ServerConfiguration {
  @Configuration
  @EnableResourceServer
  protected static class ResourceServerConfiguration extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) {
      resources.resourceId("OAuth2 Server");
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
      // @formatter:off
      http
          .authorizeRequests()
          .antMatchers("/oauth/token").permitAll()
          .antMatchers("/*").authenticated();
      // @formatter:on
    }
  }
}
```

Then there's the security configuration itself:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

  private final ApiUserDetailsService userDetailsService;

  @Autowired
  public WebSecurityConfiguration(ApiUserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    this.userDetailsService = userDetailsService;
  }

  @Override
  protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService);
  }

  @Bean
  @Override
  public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
    return super.authenticationManagerBean();
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: That warning is not something specific to using oauth. This is something that will happen with Jersey (I think mostly with Tomcat) when you are using `appliction/x-www-form-urlencoded`. It just telling you that if you want to consume the form parameters in your Jersey resource method, you should use `@FormParam` (an not some other means). To me, it seems like if you are getting this warning, then oauth is not configured correctly, because the oauth endpoint should not even be going through Jersey. It should just go spring-security.

Comment: @peeskillet thanks. But I assume if the endpoint doesn't go through Jersey (as you can see in the configuration) then why is it printing the warning for the OAuth endpoint?

Comment: The point is that it's _not_ supposed to go through Jersey. Spring Security is a servlet filter which is out side the scope of the Jersey application. So If Jersey is accepting the request for the oauth endpoint, then something is wrong. For some reason Spring Security isn't handling the request. And I'm not really sure what that reason could be.

Comment: I haven't really working with oauth with spring security. Are the endpoints configured a Spring MVC controllers are are the endpoints just handle with spring security filters? If they are handled as Spring MVC controllers, one problem would be if you are using `/*` (the default) as the Jersey path configuration. This would cause the MVC controllers not to be reached.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that Jersey is trying the handle the OAuth endpoint, which it shouldn't be. The reason is that the default mapping for Jersey is `/*`, which means that it will handle requests for all URLs. You can change that in a couple of ways:

1. Add an `@ApplicationPath` on top of your `ResourceConfig` subclass with a different mapping

   ```
   @Component
   @ApplicationPath("/api")
   public class JerseyConfig extends ResourceConfig {}
   ```
2. You can add the mapping in your `application.properties` file

   ```
   spring.jersey.application-path=/api
   ```

What this will do is prefix `/api` to all your Jersey endpoints, and also cause Jersey not to handle all request, only ones that begin with `/api`.

Comment: Gosh, thank you! I was facing the same issue, but on basic authentication. This is a hard one to find out for Spring newbies.