# OAuth 2 Java Rest API

Tags: oauth-2.0, jersey-2.0, spring-security-oauth2

I have Rest API which require authentication. The application is completely written in java. Is there any libraries present for oauth server side implementation for Rest API ?

I have already checked the spring ouath2 security but I am not sure about the support towards Jersey library as I am using it for development. Can you suggest libraries or documentation for ouath authentication in java

Comment: If outsourcing the authentication is possible for you, take a look at KeyCloak and the Adapter: https://www.keycloak.org/

Comment: The application is not open to public and won't have access to internet. So for my case I need a oauth server running within my app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring Security appears to be the only framework that provides complete implementation for Oauth 2.0 specifications. Spring supports almost all of JAX-RS implementations (including Jersey).

You might need to tweak these [Jersey properties](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html#JERSEY) to suit your needs.

[Check out this known customization required when using Jersey.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43778355/2801909)

[Spring Security OAuth 2.0 developer guide](https://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html).